# VB Byval I don't need it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I don't need this declaration because it only makes my code big and unreadable.

Is there a way to make Visual Studio (VS) not add it automatically. Every time I remove it, it is added back by VS.

```
Function DoStuff(Tom As String)
```

NOT

```
Function DoStuff(ByVal Tom As String)
```

Comment: There's no `ByVal` keyword. But I'm not a VB developer, so I'll stay out of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off pretty formatting at Tools/Options/Text Editor/Basic/VB Specific/Pretty Listing (reformatting) of code.

Comment: I don't know why you want to do that, but I did answer your question.

Comment: I think this will remove some other formatting features that i need so ill just leave it as it is.

Comment: The only answer is turning off pretty formatting. Your question is a pet peeve. A petty issue at best. Sorry to be so blunt.

Answer (score 9):

It actually makes your code more clear to the non-believers. I don't think they hurt readability of the code, rather the opposite.

Comment: What's a non-believer?

Comment: @JSS Someone who does not believe. By extension, someone who's not been told about the stuff you're doing.

Comment: <rant>ByVal is the default way to pass values in VB.Net. Why do you feel like being explicit using the keyword is helpful? Does the viewpoint that being verbose and explicit make you a believer in the VB.Net way of doing things?</rant>

Comment: The non-initiated does not know that ByVal is the default in VB and thus they may be confused. Being verbose doesn't make you a believer, it makes your code more accessible to non-believers. And if you want to rant, then <rant>why the hell would you want to do VB anyway??</rant>

Comment: I'm not trying to troll here. Please excuse my tone. My initial comment was probably from a day when I was having a bad experience with VB at work. I don't prefer VB primarily because of it's verboseness, but I do appreciate some of the features it allows that the CLR and C# do not. Thanks for the quid-pro-quo. Regarding why I use it. Out of necessity. Legacy Codebase.

Answer (score 7):

Install Visual Studio 2010 Service pack 1. It doesn't insert the ByVal declaration.